# passing get parameters through named route and then to controller model; stringify_keys!

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey, I'm just learning ruby on rails and I've been stumped on this for awhile now.

Here's my url request:

```
  http://192.168.2.20:8080/Location/new/123.123,-123.123/
```

Here's my routes.rb:

```
  map.connect '/Location/new/:coords/', :controller => 'Location', :action => 'new', :coords => /\d+.\d+,-\d+.\d+/
  map.connect '/Location/list/', :controller => 'Location', :action => 'list'
  map.connect '/Location/create/', :controller => 'Location', :action => 'create'
```

Here's my location_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @coords = Location.new(params[:coords])
  end
```

Here's the error message it gives me:

```
  NoMethodError in LocationController#new
  undefined method `stringify_keys!' for "123.123,-123.123":String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location.new expects a Hash as its argument, in location_controller.rb you should use:

```
def new
  @location = Location.new( { :coords => params[:coords] } )
end
```

Assuming the coords is the name of the field you want to use. Then in your view or subsequent code you can use `@location.coords` to get the value.